# React state values are not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following JSON data which need to be updated in `src` state in every 5 seconds. I have tried printing data in the console which is showing completely fine but it's not getting updated in state after each sleep of 5 seconds.

**Sample JSON Data of Logs Json**

```
var Logs={
        Router:[{"a":"1"}],
        Validation:[{"b":"1"}],
        Transformation:[{"c":"1"}],
        Execution:[{"d":"1"}],
        Response:[{"e":"1"}]

    }
```

**Here is my code**

```
    var LogData={};
    LogData["Router"]=Logs.Router;

    //Requesting Router        
       _this.setState({
            cssRequest:ClassProgressDone,
            src:LogData,
        });
        console.log(LogData);   

        _this.sleep(5000).then(() => {
            LogData["Validation"]=Logs.Validation;
            console.log(LogData);      

            _this.setState({
                cssValidate:ClassProgressDone,
                src:LogData,
            });

            _this.sleep(5000).then(() => {
                LogData["Transformation"]=Logs.Transformation;
                console.log(LogData);       
                _this.setState({
                    cssTransform:ClassProgressDone,
                    src:LogData,
                });

                _this.sleep(5000).then(() => {
                    LogData["Execution"]=Logs.Execution;
                    console.log(LogData);
                    _this.setState({
                        cssExecution:ClassProgressDone,
                        src:LogData,
                    });

                        _this.sleep(5000).then(() => {
                            LogData["Response"]=Logs.Response;
                            console.log(LogData);
                            _this.setState({
                                cssCompleted:ClassProgressDone,
                                src:LogData,
                            });
                        });
                });


            });


        });
```

**sleep function**

```
 sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: what is the implementation of this.sleep? and is this code in componentDidMount or something?

Comment: @stilllife Added the Sleep function in question. This executes on button click event.

Comment: Can u check with react dev tools if the state is indeed updated? can you show the constructor and where you redefine this with _this?

Comment: _this is resides in the same function of this code as `var _this=this;`

Comment: Instead of nesting the sleeps. Have you thought about using setInterval()?

Comment: i would try to clone the LogData using Object. assign or the spread operator because set state might want immutable objects to detect a change

Comment: No, I have not tried setInterval(). Please help in using the same